# Passing data from Page to Page Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

This is my page

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="VMO.APP.Maga.ListaLiberaInsertPage"
             Title="Lista libera - Inserimento">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Label Text="Cliente: "></Label>
                <Button Text="Seleziona&#10;Cliente" x:Name="ClienteSelect"></Button>
            </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Label Text="Magazzino: "></Label>
                <Button Text="Seleziona&#10;Magazzino" x:Name="MagazzinoSelect"></Button>
            </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Label Text="Codice: "></Label>
                <Entry x:Name="BarcodeFilterEntry" Placeholder="Digitare il Barcode" />
            </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Label Text="Descrizione: " x:Name="DescArticolo"></Label>
                <Entry x:Name="Barcode" ></Entry>
            </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Label Text="Quantità: "></Label>
                <Entry x:Name="QuantitaEntry" ></Entry>
            </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Button Text="Aggiungi" x:Name="AggiungiButton" Clicked="OnAddClicked"></Button>
            </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

File .cs

```
public partial class ListaLiberaInsertPage : ContentPage
    {

        public ListaLiberaInsertPage (Session session)
        {
            InitializeComponent ();
            OnPageLoad(session);
        }

        public ListaLiberaInsertPage(Session session, BpId cliente)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            OnPageLoad(session);
            ClienteSelect.Text = string.Format("{0} ({1})",cliente.CardName, cliente.CardCode);
        }

        public ListaLiberaInsertPage(Session session, Magazzino magazzino)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            OnPageLoad(session);
            MagazzinoSelect.Text = magazzino.WarehouseName;
        }

        protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            BarcodeFilterEntry.Focus();
        }

        void OnPageLoad(Session session)
        {

            BarcodeFilterEntry.Completed += (sender, e) =>
            {
                OnSubmitClickedAsync(sender, e, session);
            };

            ClienteSelect.Clicked += (sender, e) =>
            {
                OnOpenClienteSelectClicked(sender, e, session);
            };

            MagazzinoSelect.Clicked += (sender, e) =>
            {
                OnOpenMagazzinoSelectClicked(sender, e, session);
            };

        }

        private async void OnOpenClienteSelectClicked(object sender, EventArgs e, Session session)
        {
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new ClientiListPage(session));
        }

        private async void OnOpenMagazzinoSelectClicked(object sender, EventArgs e, Session session)
        {
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new MagaListPage(session));
        }

    }
```

This instead is one of the two pages called from page A ... I should find a way to call B from A select an element and then return to A and change the Text of the Button and the same thing to do it from A to C ... only if I click on C the button that changes B returns to the original Text ... I do not use MVVM

```
public partial class ClientiListPage : ContentPage
    {
        public ObservableCollection<BpId> bpIdList;

        public ClientiListPage(Session session)
        {

            InitializeComponent();

            OnPageLoad(session);

        }

        protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            BpFilterEntry.Focus();
        }

        private void OnPageLoad(Session session)
        {

            list.ItemTapped += (sender, ItemTappedEventArgs) =>
            {
                OnItemTappedAsync(sender, ItemTappedEventArgs, session);
            }; 
        }


        private async void OnItemTappedAsync(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e, Session session)
        {
            var item = e.Item;
            Navigation.InsertPageBefore(new ListaLiberaInsertPage(session, item as BpId),this);
            await Navigation.PopAsync();
            ((ListView)sender).ItemsSource = null;
        }
    }
```